# Cassandra - Internal data storage when no clustering key is specified

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to understand the scenario when no clustering key is specified in a table definition.

If a table has only a partition key and no clustering key, what order the rows under the same partition are stored in? Is it even allowed to have multiple rows under the same partition when no clustering key exists? I tried searching for it online but couldn't get a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the below explanation from Cassandra user group so posting it here in case someone else is looking for the same info:

"Note that a table always has a partition key, and that if the table has
no clustering columns, then every partition of that table is only
comprised of a single row (since the primary key uniquely identifies
rows and the primary key is equal to the partition key if there is no
clustering columns)."

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/ddl.html#the-partition-key